# add() method in Set implementation in Java does not work

Tags: java, arraylist, set

I am trying to implement my own `Set` with an ArrayList in Java. I am testing the `add()` method and somehow it wont add the elements in the Set. I know that if an element is added in the ArrayList then `List.add(input)` will return true, so maybe the problem lies there. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?
This is the implementation of the Set `add()`method:

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

```
public class Set<E> implements Collection<E> {
    private ArrayList<E> List = new ArrayList<>();

    public boolean add(E input) {
        if (contains(input)) {
            return false;
        }
        return List.add(input);
    }
```

And this is the test method I run :

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestSet {

    public static Set<Integer> set = new Set<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a set :");
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        set = new Set<Integer>();

        set.add(userInput.nextInt());
        System.out.println(set);
    }
```

The output I get on the console after running the method is:

```
Enter a set :
1
Set@677327b6
```

Comment: What makes you think it's not getting added? Nothing in what you've shown suggests that.

Comment: by the convention you should use lowercase names for fields so List should be list

Comment: Note that extending `AbstractSet` is a better way to start implementing your own `Set`. For one thing, it's a real `java.util.Set`.

Comment: Have your custom `Set` extend `java.util.AbstractSet` to inherit a default `toString` implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not using `toString` method or not using it correctly you need to use :

```
public class Set<E> implements Collection<E> {

    private ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return list.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mark No it is not, you can't return `ArrayList` in a method which should return String try it and you will see

Comment: @Mark usully when you use `Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)); System.out.println(set);` what you get? you get `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and not `Set [1, 2, 3, 4]` this why I use just `list.toString()` which will return `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: hey thanks a lot this worked! could you please explain to me why it is necessary to override the toString() method?

Comment: and about `it is necessary to override the toString()` because without it you will by default you are using the toString of `Object.toString` which will return what you get without toString

Comment: sorry I got that wrong!
thanks a lot for the explanation